# Only accept 2 digits integer array in django model form

Tags: html, django, django-forms, modelform

How to make a form field that accept 2 digit numeric array in frontend. if someone enter more then 2 digit or string then The input value is automatically validated to ensure it is a properly formatted 2 digit integer array.

right

[image]

wrong below

[image]

i want validation like this:

[image]

**My work**

models.py

```
class Jodi(models.Model):
  numb = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Jodi
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Jodi
        fields = ['numb',]
```

views.py

```
if request.method=='POST':
        fm = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            numbers = fm.cleaned_data['numb']
            numbers1 = []
            for x in numbers:
                if x:
                    numbers1.append(x)
            X=Jodi.objects.create(numb=numbers1,)
            X.save()
else:
    fm = MyModelForm()
    return render(request,'myapp/home.html',{'form':fm})
```

home.html

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        
      {{ form.as_p }}
```

Comment: i dont want to validate it from backed, i want to validate in frontend. ex-from bootstrap.

Comment: To do the validation on the front-end, first, specify the selector using the ``attrs`` (id, class) on the form field. Write the Javascript code to select and read the input field value and implement validation logic. The same logic that you don't want to be on the back-end.

Comment: why don't you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `widget` and `attrs` to set a `pattern` to form field.

Use pattern `([0-9]{2})(,\s*[0-9]{2})*` to have spaces after comma OR Use `([0-9]{2})(,[0-9]{2})*` to have no spaces after comma.

**Using widget:**

```py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # code
    numb = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'pattern':'([0-9]{2})(,[0-9]{2})*',}))
    # code
```

Sample pattern in action:

```html
<html !doctype>    
    <body>
        <form action="" method="get">  
            <label for="number_array">Number Array: </label>  
            <input type="text" 
               placeholder="00,11,22"  
               pattern="([0-9]{2})(,\s*[0-9]{2})*"  
               autofocus  
               required>  
            <button>Go </button>  
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
if fm.is_valid():
    numbers = fm.cleaned_data['numb']
    for n in numbers.split(','):
        if not n.isdigit() or len(n)!=2:
            # return render new form with error of not a valid input, input should be 2 digits numbers seprated by comma
    X=Jodi.objects.create(numb=numbers1,)
    X.save()
```

Comment: i dont want to validate it from backed, i want to validate in frontend. ex-from bootstrap